# Will the cold starts of my AWS Lambda function take longer if I use an ECR image/containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

Will the cold starts of my AWS Lambda function take longer if I use a image from ECR instead of a jar from S3 as my source code? I'm thinking that yes, because the image is larger due to the additional OS layer (even though... the regular Lambda should have some OS layer as well), but I couldn't find any performance benchmarks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I'm surprised at the conclusion of the other answers here.

**IT DEPENDS**

Linked earlier, this [blog post performs](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/) data tests. From that post:

[image]
[image]

If your function is a pure function. It'll perform way better (1st picture) as most have said, but once your function acts more like a Framework the size of the zip grows and all it takes is a few megs and S3 is simply too slow.

To be clear, your container/program needs to have a fast start time, but that's irrespective of the size or lambda.

That second graph is incredible, 5GB container loading in `< 2s`.

Comment: The above charts are basically wrong. Lambda uses lazy loading for container storage. If you don't touch every byte of that 5GB, then it's not actually loaded, and you'll see the same load times as for a tiny container. What's more, Lambda has multiple levels of cache, which makes it almost impossible to properly test cold start times. If you're doing repeated testing of even similar containers, even your cold starts will be pulling from a nearby cache, rather than going all the way to S3

Comment: @jameslol your response and my answer can still both be right. Our webserver and background worker use the same container, but the web codepath's cold start times are tightly controlled. The bg worker loads heavy img processing, science libs >7s. Web server still responds <4s from cold due to tricks AWS does as you state, not the whole thing is loaded, but the server still responds. Regardless, the answer is definitely correct against the question.

Comment: Interesting insight, but no, i think it's misleading at best to say that huge containers load fast, without stating that this is only if you don't use any of it. If you're loading 5gb containers and using so little of them that they're loading in 1 second, the take-home message is that you're doing something weird, not "it's so quick"

Comment: @jameslol Sure, if you didn't actually understand my answer. That was the line `To be clear, your container/program needs to have a fast start time, but that's irrespective of the size or lambda.` There is nothing stopping you from putting the DVD of the Matrix onto your container. It will be faster than S3, which is the question. The post also starts with `It depends` in big, black bold.

Comment: Sorry if my bluntness got us off on the wrong foot. What I'm trying to say is that the start time is actually not irrespective of size or lambda. I have containers which initialise very quickly on my local machine (200ms) and very slowly on Lambda (2-4 seconds). This is because every file (block) in every library that is lazy-loaded has to be pulled using a separate call to S3. A process which is normally CPU-bound is now suddenly very much IO-bound.

Comment: What's worse, the testing methodology for the two charts above are totally different. In the first chart, a heap of NPM libraries are initialised, which is why it takes 4 seconds for 35MB. (No way Lamba is spending 4 seconds on the IO to download 35MB from S3.) Whereas in the second chart, the author states that the container is just filled with random text files. So the container test was actually doing less work than the non-container test, which as displayed here falsely gives the impression that once your package size gets to 35MB or more, you should switch to a container

Answer (score 8):

"Lambda also optimizes the image and caches it close to where the functions runs so cold start times are the same as for .zip archives" from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you will have **longer cold starts**, resulting in **much higher response times**.

It is really dependent on the image you're downloading from ECR but in general, it will be slower as a Docker container is being used instead of Lambda managing the runtime environment for you (which reduces the time to it takes to start a new execution environment for cold Lambdas).

The main cause is the *size of the ECR image*, which is also why there is a limit on large Lambda ZIP archives.

You can see here how the size will affect the 2 tasks that run during cold start, defined by AWS as *Download your code* & *Start new execution environment*.

[image: cold start duration tasks & invocation duration tasks]

**I would advise you to definitely use the managed runtime as opposed to containers unless you need to use them as it will automatically result in faster execution.**

Comment: This makes sense from a theoretical standpoint (at least as far as cold starts go), but do you have any evidence to back the "much higher latency" claim?

Comment: @dskrvk I've rephrased to clarify what I meant - is that better?

Comment: Note that with latest optimizations for containerized Lambda, currently it may actually be the other way around: https://aaronstuyvenberg.com/posts/containers-on-lambda

Answer (score 3):

Docker images will be definitely slower cold start.
This is because of bigger size and additional OS. Lambda loads your code into its managed environment instead loading you whole docker image.

Links for reference:
Some graphs comparing docker with native java lambda:
https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/

Additional information about lambda containers:
https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-lambda-container-images/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, packaging a lambda as a container image rather than a zip will lead to longer cold starts.

There are 2 reasons for this:

1. Container images tend to be larger, thus taking more time to load.
2. Containers need to initialize the underlying operating system.

In general, use a container over a plain lambda when you benefit from having the underlying OS functionality. Otherwise, stick to zip files.